# Is there a particular reason why jQuery's addClass() is not right-trimming?

Tags: jquery, trim, addclass

```
<div id="myDiv" class=" blueberry mango "></div>
```

If we use the [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

```
$("#myDiv").addClass("carrot");
```

The class for `myDiv` is now [`"(no-space)blueberry mango(double-space)carrot"`](http://jsfiddle.net/AG8QM/2/)

There is a `left-trim`, but there are double spaces between mango and carrot because there were no `right-trim`

- Is there a particular reason why jQuery's `addClass()` is not
  right-trimming?
- Or the left-trim was not even intended?

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with speed. Is this causing an error?

Comment: This shouldn't cause any errors, so does it really matter?

Comment: It is an interesting question nonetheless.

Comment: Editer: I improved yopur jsFiddle for a better view

Comment: FYI, it should be no big deal to have an occasional extra space between classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like jQuery is doing the trim after adding the class. See jquery addclass code below,

```
addClass: function( value ) {
    var classNames, i, l, elem,
        setClass, c, cl;

    if ( jQuery.isFunction( value ) ) {
        return this.each(function( j ) {
            jQuery( this ).addClass( value.call(this, j, this.className) );
        });
    }

    if ( value && typeof value === "string" ) {
        classNames = value.split( rspace );

        for ( i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++ ) {
            elem = this[ i ];

            if ( elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
                if ( !elem.className && classNames.length === 1 ) {
                    elem.className = value;

                } else {
               //HERE IS APPENDS ALL CLASS IT NEEDS TO ADD
                    setClass = " " + elem.className + " ";

                    for ( c = 0, cl = classNames.length; c < cl; c++ ) {
                        if ( !~setClass.indexOf( " " + classNames[ c ] + " " ) ) {
                            setClass += classNames[ c ] + " ";
                        }
                    }
                    elem.className = jQuery.trim( setClass );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return this;
}
```

So it's like below,

`jQuery.trim(" blueberry mango " + " " + "carrot")`

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because jQuery is appending the class to the list of classes and then running `trim` on the entire string.

Have a look at the [source for `addClass`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L39) to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source, I'm guessing there's no reason for that:

```
setClass = " " + elem.className + " ";

for ( c = 0, cl = classNames.length; c < cl; c++ ) {
    if ( !~setClass.indexOf( " " + classNames[ c ] + " " ) ) {
        setClass += classNames[ c ] + " ";
    }
}
elem.className = jQuery.trim( setClass );
```

True, having a whitespace before and after each class helps to find if the new class (being added) is already there or not, but still they could replace the first line with:

```
setClass = " " + jQuery.trim(elem.className) + " ";
```

and it still would work the same way...